# 534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections using FTP in C#.net

Tags: c#, ssl, ftp

I am working on Windows Application. I want to check list of file and download the latest file. using following code, I am getting I check the list of files available.

I was getting following error when `request.EnableSsl = false`.

> The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol
>   violation

I have read some references to resolve it. I have added self sign certificate code but now I am getting following error.

> The remote server returned an error: (534) 534 Local policy on server
>   does not allow TLS secure connections.

When I debug the code, I have realized that the debug pointer doesn't check the certificate code.

Here is the code:

```
private void checkLatestUpdate()
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.abc.com/myfolder/downloadsfile/");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mytestuser", "my123pass*a");
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.EnableSsl = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ServicePointManager_ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        //getlist of files
    }
    catch(){}
}

//check license 
public static bool ServicePointManager_ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

Can anybody suggest me for both the issue?

> 1- The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol
>   violation.
>
> 2- The remote server returned an error: (534) 534 Local policy on server
>   does not allow TLS secure connections.

Comment: 534 Local **policy on server** does not allow TLS secure connections - if the server forbids use of TLS then  you can not enforce it in the client. Instead you must make changes on the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Can you tell me about the first error : `The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation.` I have used Certificate Authentication because of  first error. Am I correct for it?

Comment: Since the server does not speak TLS no TLS handshake is done and thus no certificate is send and thus no certificate validation can take place. For more information about how to solve the problem one would need to know what protocol data are exchanged between client and server, i.e. packet capture or similar.